# Declarative router link not clearing model in Vue component using VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Developing a task scheduler the path '/task?id=10' fills the component model with an async response with the task information, that works ok.

In the navigation bar I have the following router link:

```
<router-link to="/task">New Task</router-link>
```

So I am using the same path and component for creating a new task and editing existing ones all based in if "id" parameter is present or not.

The problem is that if I am in path '/task?id=10' and I fill some model fields, then I click the router-link pointing to '/task' (no params) it changes the browser URL but it does not clear the component model so the input data persists.

How can I restart/reload the component when landing it through a declarative router-link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make parent-child component. Parent component is on /task route, child would be on '/task/10. More, [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html). Also, you don't need to append '?id=', just /task/10.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/task', component: Task,
      children: [
        { path: ':id', component: TaskId }
      ]
    }]
 });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nazgul_mamasheva/unrhdpeg/1/)